# No resource identifier found for

Tags: android, refactoring

When I try to refactor an app, I get hundreds of "`No resource identifier found for (...)`" Errors "in package com.app"

How can I solve this Problem?

I already tried to replace the values to the new package Name but the error remains the same.

The Errors happen at such code parts:

```
<com.example.app
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:latin="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.fa.ime"
    android:id="@+id/LatinkeyboardBaseView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/keyboard_bottom_padding"
    android:background="@drawable/keyboard_dark_background"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    latin:keyBackground="@drawable/btn_keyboard_key_gingerbread"
    latin:keyTextStyle="bold"
    />
```

Comment: What exactly did you refactor?

Comment: The package Name of an app (com.example.app)

Answer (score 0):

R class, used to access resources in android, linked to use package name from Android.manifest. Replace in all imports of R class old package name for new package name. Unfortunately you only can use standard text search in this case.

As far as i know, only this class uses package name from manifest, so other imports should be fine.

I don't use Android support package, but if you using it, in every layout associated with activity, there can be parameter named `tools:context` which include reference to activity. If you changed package name of app, this also could be a source of your problems.

Comment: Yes, this is what I normally do in the Android code. But what about normal layout files?